# The size of the square is calculated incorrectly | Java libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

I am creating a game in which there is a 10x10 map and I need to calculate the size of these squares so that they all fit on the screen.

`rect_x_end, rect_y_end` The size of the square by x and y

`screen_x, screen_y` Screen Size

`len_map_x, len_map_y` Map width and length = 10

I calculated the size of the square like this:

```
rect_x_end = screen_x / len_map_x
rect_y_end = screen_y / len_map_y
```

example:

```
64 = 640 / 10
48 = 480 / 10
```

In this example, everything works correctly, but as soon as I start resizing the screen, this method gives an incorrect result.

I was doing something similar to python (pygame) and everything worked there.

kucer0043.java

```
package com.kucer0043.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;

public class kucer0043 extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private int map_size;

    @Override
    public void create () {
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        map_size = 10; // square map size
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
        int rect_x_end = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / map_size;
        int rect_y_end = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / map_size;
        int map_x = Gdx.input.getX() / rect_x_end;
        int map_y = Gdx.input.getY() / rect_y_end;
        int x = map_x * rect_x_end;
        int y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - (map_y + 1) * rect_y_end;
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(0f,1f,0f,0f);
        shapeRenderer.rect(x,y, rect_x_end, rect_y_end);
        shapeRenderer.end();

    }
    
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }
}
```

Comment: 10 is the size of the map by x and y

Comment: I use integer for all variables.

Comment: I expect that I will get the size of a square.

Comment: What is the incorrect result?

Comment: I'll attach the code to the question right now and you'll see.

Comment: Try changing the screen size.

Comment: "Try changing the screen size" - we shouldn't have to run the code to see the problem. It's good that we *can* run the code (assuming it just compiles when libgdx is available), but the question should include details of what goes wrong. It would also be much easier to read if you'd follow Java naming conventions, and ideally reduce it to a [mcve] - I suspect you can reproduce the problem with a lot of the code removed.

Comment: i changed the code

Comment: When you say "screen", do you mean "window"? As in you aren't changing full screen resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The projection matrix of your `ShapeRenderer` is calculated on initialization,you need to re-calculate it whenever the window changes size.

There are a few ways of achieving this, the simplest might be to just create a new `ShapeRenderer` when the window resizes:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
}
```